Equality in Gagliardo Niremberg Sobolev type of problem

Suppose there is a function $u\in C_c^2(\mathbb{R}^4)$ that attains the Gagliardo Niremberg Sobolev bound:
$$M := \sup_{f \in C_c^1(\mathbb{R}^4)} \frac{\|f\|_{L^4(\mathbb{R}^4)}}{\|\nabla f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^4)}}.
$$
And $\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^4)}=1$. Then, prove that it satisfies the differential equation:
$$M^4\Delta u+u^3=0$$

Let us define $g=M^4 \Delta u+u^3$. The condition that the supremum is attained teaches us that:
$$\int u^4dx=M^4=M^4\int\nabla u\cdot \nabla u dx=-M^4\int u \Delta u dx $$
$$\therefore\langle g, u \rangle_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^4)}=0 $$
More generally, if we take $\phi$ to be a $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^4)$ function, we have that from Holder:
$$\left|\int g\phi dx\right|=\left|-M^4\int\nabla u \cdot \nabla \phi dx+\int u^3\phi dx\right|\leq$$
$$ M^4 \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^4)} \|\nabla \phi\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^4)}+\|u\|_{L^4(\mathbb{R}^4)}^3\|\phi\|_{L^4(\mathbb{R}^4)}\leq$$
$$M^4  \|\nabla \phi\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^4)}+M^3 M\|\nabla \phi\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^4)}=2M^4\|\nabla \phi\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^4)}$$
Substituting $\phi$ by $\phi(x/n+x_o)$ means we explore this inequality nicely:
$$\int g(x)\phi\left(\frac{ x}{n}+x_o\right)dx\leq 2M^4 \left(\int \left|\nabla\phi\left(\frac{ x}{n}+x_o\right)\right|^2\frac{1}{n^2}dx \right)^{1/2}=$$
$$2M^4 \left(\int\left|\nabla \phi (x)\right|^2\frac{1}{n}dx \right)^{1/2}=\frac{2M^4\|\nabla \phi\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^4)}}{\sqrt{n}}$$
$$\therefore \sqrt{n} \int g(x) \phi\left(\frac xn +x_o\right)dx\leq 2M^4\|\nabla \phi\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^4)}$$
Next I assumed $g$ had more regularity so that we could take $\phi= g$ which yields in the limit (using Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem and the above inequality) that:
$$g(x_o)\int g(x) dx =0$$
Hence if $g$ is non zero, we have so far that $\int gudx=0$ and with more regularity on $g$ that $\int g dx=0$. I am not quite sure how to continue. I also tried taking other $\phi$, which decay slowly but it didn't seem to work.

This follows by observing that if $u_t$ is any compactly supported variation of $u$, where $u_0 = u$ and $$ \dot{u} = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|{t=0}u_t,$$  then \begin{align*}
\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|{t=0}\log\left(\frac{\left(\int u_t^4\right)^{1/2}}{\int |\nabla u_t|^2}\right) &= 0. \end{align*} The PDE follows by calculating the right side and initegrating by parts.

@Deane, thank you so much. If you write this ipsis litteris as a solution, I will accept it as the best answer.

Following Deane's precious solution with a little more detail:
Let $v$ be a function of compact support and define $h(t)$ to be:
$$h(t)=\frac{\int (u+tv)^4 dx}{(\int |\nabla u+t\nabla v|^2 dx)^2}$$
There is a maximum at $t=0$ and $h$ is differentiable there by Leibniz's Theorem.  Let us rewrite $h'(0)=0$ as:
$$4\int(u+tv)^3 v dx\left(\int |\nabla u+t\nabla v|^2 dx\right)^2-$$
$$\left.2 \int |\nabla u+t\nabla v|^2 dx \int 2(\nabla u+t \nabla v)\cdot\nabla vdx\int(u+tv)^4dx\right|_{t=0} =0$$
$$\int u^3 v dx-\int \nabla u \cdot \nabla vdx \int u^4 dx=0$$
$$\therefore \int(u^3+M^4\Delta u)v dx=0$$
Because this holds for any $v$ of compact support, we need $u^3+M^4\Delta u=0$.

Much better to have you write the answer!

@Deane, I would have never thought of this without you, that is why I wanted you to write your comment as an answer so I could show my appreciation for your insight. :)
